# How to set xscreensaver to use blank mode without GUI?

Tags: xscreensaver

After installing `xscreensaver` in Arch Linux my laptop has started displaying fancy, battery-depleting animations when nobody is looking. How do I configure this to use the `blank` mode via the command line (i.e., without `xscreensaver-demo`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [configure](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/man1.html) this in either `~/.Xresources`:

```
xscreensaver.mode: blank
```

or `~/.xscreensaver`:

```
mode: blank
```

To verify:

```
xrdb -load ~/.Xresources
killall xscreensaver
xscreensaver -no-splash &
```

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>, and stare into the unblinking eye of infinity.